# Derivation from $M(G)$ to $C_0(G)$

Tags: supramenability

We know that $C_0(G)$ is $M(G)$-bimodule by $M(G)=(C_0(G))^*$ for locally compact group $G$.

How we characterize the derivations and  inner derivations $D: M(G)\to C_0(G)$ ?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to ask for a characterization of the inner derivations, because they are given to you by definition

Comment: Presumably what you actually want to know are conditions that ensure every derivation $D:M(G)\to C_0(G)$ is inner. I don't recall seeing a full answer to this question, but it is certainly sufficient to assume G is abelian and discrete.

Comment: I am not sure what happens if G is the circle group, or a non-abelian discrete amenable group. Perhaps this would be an interesting project to investigate yourself?

Comment: Finally, I don't understand why you have chosen the tag "supramenability". That is a special definition which does not seem related to your question.